# How do I run shell commands from Swift 3 (Xcode 8) using Interface Builder?

Tags: swift3, applescript, xcode8

First time using Xcode, typically I stick to AppleScript for simple applications but I'm looking to branch out and make use of a GUI.

I want to be able to execute the system "zip" command from Swift (3) in Xcode 8 with some arguments with a button press.

The code I have below when run produces the following error:

**zip error: Nothing to do! ( -r -j ~/Desktop/SystemLogs/iLog.zip ~/Library/Logs/iLog -x *.DS_Store)**

What am I doing wrong in trying to run this shell command from swift? Any assistance is appreciated.

```
@IBAction func gButton(_ sender: NSButtonCell) {

    let zip1 = Process()
    zip1.launchPath = "/usr/bin/zip"
    zip1.arguments = [" -r -j ~/Desktop/SystemLogs/Logs.zip ~/Library/Logs -x *.DS_Store"]
    zip1.launch()

    sender.isEnabled = false

    zip1.waitUntilExit()

    sender.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: The `*` expansion is a property of the shell you're using (e.g. `bash`), `zip` doesn't know what to do with it

Comment: Tried pulling that portion "-x *.DS_Store" from the code and it still produces the error zip error: Nothing to do! ( -r -j ~/Desktop/SystemLogs/iLog.zip ~/Library/Logs/iLog)

Comment: Same thing applies to `~`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass a shell command line to zip. It is the shell's job to break a command line into individual arguments, handle pathname expansion, setup I/O redirection, etc., etc. The actual command invoked, zip in your case, is passed an array of the individual arguments after the shell has done its job, any I/O redirection is setup, etc.

You *either* need to pass an array of the individual arguments, e.g. `@[ @"-r", @"-j", ... ]` and handle the pathname expansion yourself *or* you can instead invoke the shell itself and have it do all that work for you. Look up the manual page for the shell you wish to use (bash, tcsh, etc.) and you'll find it has an option, probably `-c`, which takes a complete command line as a single parameter and parses and executes it.

HTH

Comment: CRD thank you!! The bash -c option worked perfectly!